# How to have full directory path always shown in mac terminal (like linux terminal)

Tags: macos, ubuntu, terminal.app

In my ubuntu terminal I have always current directory shown completely. Just like this:

> blabla@blublu:~/music/my_album/classical/beethoven$

But in my Mac (Mac OS X 10.6.5) terminal does not show the full path and it is like this:

> blabas-MacBook-Pro:classical beethoven$

Is there anyway that I change mac terminal behavior to act like linux terminal?

Comment: there must be a screen in preferences of Terminal App. which you can change behaviors.

Comment: Linux terminals don't magically show the full path; it depends on your settings. Some linux distros configure things to show the full path by default, some don't. It all depends on the $PS1 variable. (See Asmus's answer.)

Comment: Have you guys tried this on newer macks? Its simply not working for me. It adds the raw regex string on the terminal `\u@\H [\w]$`, not the correspondent values

Answer (score 125):

To let bash return "user@hostname:path/to/directory$" as your prompt, add the following line to your ~/.bash_profile:

```
export PS1='\u@\H:\w$'
```

or

```
export PS1='\u@\H:\w$ '
```

if you like having a space between the $ and the command

to make the changes take effect immediately, run the following command in every open window (or restart Terminal):

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

**EDIT**:
A list of available strings can be found in the paragraph "PROMPTING" in the man page for bash (`man bash`):

> PROMPTING
>
> ```
>   When executing interactively, bash displays the primary prompt PS1 when it is ready to read a command, and the secondary prompt PS2 when it needs more input to complete a command.  Bash allows these prompt strings  to  be  customized  by
>    inserting a number of backslash-escaped special characters that are decoded as follows:
>           \a     an ASCII bell character (07)
>           \d     the date in "Weekday Month Date" format (e.g., "Tue May 26")
>           \D{format}
>                  the format is passed to strftime(3) and the result is inserted into the prompt string; an empty format results in a locale-specific time representation.  The braces are required
>           \e     an ASCII escape character (033)
>           \h     the hostname up to the first `.'
>           \H     the hostname
>           \j     the number of jobs currently managed by the shell
>           \l     the basename of the shell's terminal device name
>           \n     newline
>           \r     carriage return
>           \s     the name of the shell, the basename of $0 (the portion following the final slash)
>           \t     the current time in 24-hour HH:MM:SS format
>           \T     the current time in 12-hour HH:MM:SS format
>           \@     the current time in 12-hour am/pm format
>           \A     the current time in 24-hour HH:MM format
>           \u     the username of the current user
>           \v     the version of bash (e.g., 2.00)
>           \V     the release of bash, version + patch level (e.g., 2.00.0)
>           \w     the current working directory, with $HOME abbreviated with a tilde
>           \W     the basename of the current working directory, with $HOME abbreviated with a tilde
>           \!     the history number of this command
>           \#     the command number of this command
>           \$     if the effective UID is 0, a #, otherwise a $
>           \nnn   the character corresponding to the octal number nnn
>           \\     a backslash
>           \[     begin a sequence of non-printing characters, which could be used to embed a terminal control sequence into the prompt
>           \]     end a sequence of non-printing characters
> ```

Comment: Or just enter that `PS1` assignment in every open window. By the way, the `export` is unnecessary.

Comment: Actually, if you don´t use export, your would be defining a shell variable, not an environment variable, so PS1 would not be passed globally to all processes.

Comment: export com is working as suggested and showing full path, but once I restart the terminal it shows only present directory (not full path). How can I keep this forever.

Comment: would it be possible to explain what `PS1`, `\u@\H:\w$` means?

Comment: @Jas I've updated my answer accordingly, don't know why I didn't do this years ago ^^

Comment: Why don't I see any difference between '\w' and '\W' on MacBook? I wanter full path, but can't see it.

Comment: @Danijel Hmm, not sure … for me, using `\w` returns `~/Documents` and `\W` returns just `Documents` (if I'm within my `/Users/myusername/Documents` folder, of course). Perhaps you didn't start a new terminal session for a change to become active? Also, if I understood you correctly, you want to use `$PWD` instead, in order to get the *full path*.

Comment: Have you guys tried this on newer macks? Its simply not working for me. It adds the raw regex string on the terminal `\u@\H [\w]$ ` not the correspondent values

Answer (score 12):

I made it to look very similar to centOS terminal on my Mac. Open bash_profile, on terminal

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

Add the following

```
# Show always fullpath on terminal
export PS1='\u@\H [\w]$ '
```

Restart Terminal and then it will looks like this

```
username@host.local [/Applications/MAMP/htdocs]$
```

Answer (score 11):

I am not sure about Mac, but in Ubuntu I've [changed the Gnome Terminal prompt](http://www.vsubhash.com/article.asp?id=13&info=Ubuntu_and_Gnome_Diary#change_terminal_prompt) with

```
PS1="\a\n\n\e[31;1m\u@\h on \d at \@\n\e[33;1m\w\e[0m\n$ "
```

Answer (score 6):

Inside PS1 value, "\w" represents the full path, where "\W" represents the current directory name only.

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/bash-prompt-escape-sequences.html

Comment: Why don't I see any difference between '\w' and '\W' on MacBook? I wanter full path, but can't see it.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to edit your `~/.bash_profile` you can also just configure your terminal-profile. Click on `Terminal > Prefences` and from there go to the `Profiles` tab and then to the `Shell` tab. Enable `[x] Run command` and enter `export PS1='\u@\H:\w$ '`.

It's just another way of doing it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just change the /w to /W to make just the current folder

in colored terminal

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\W\[\033[00m\]\$ '
```

no color terminal

```
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\W\$ '
```

I use ubuntu 16.04 and change the file in ~/.bashrc

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to make a very simple change through a framework such as `oh-my-zsh`, as explained in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27885057/zsh-theme-for-full-path-display-git-changes):

If you use the oh-my-zsh framework for instance, depending on the theme you chose to use, you'd only have to replace the `%c` character with `%~`. The reason being that `%c` shows the current folder, while `%~` shows the full path from the root.

The file where you'd want to make the change would be something like:
`~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/<chosen_theme>` 
In my case, same as the linked question, I've selected the robbyrussell theme, so the file I had to modify was:
`~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/robbyrussell.zsh-theme`

For safety, you can also copy the original `PROMPT=` line at the end of`~/.zshrc` before customising your theme.